# Why do editor scripts need to be placed in editor folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just created my own editor in unity.

```
public class ShapeEditor : Editor
{
    private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
       // Done something
    }
}
```

I didn't place it in any editor folder. It's just somewhere within my project.

Why does that work? What do I get if I place it in an editor folder? Why should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the Editor. But if you try to build an executable or app with that code, editor code will not work anymore (or even compile), because the Editor API's aren't available in Player versions.

That's why you need to put code that depends on Editor-specific API's in an Editor folder, so Unity can leave it out when building a player version.

Comment: Yes, the main reason is to avoid compilation errors caused by Editor API usage during builds. But sometimes, it is convenient to use Editor code inside a runtime script. In those cases, the editor code can be wrapped inside `#if UNITY_EDITOR` and `#endif` directives. The code will run only in Editor and will automatically be stripped from builds.